# Convert nanoseconds to days, hours, min and seconds

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I'm working in python with a pandas df and trying to convert a column that contains nanoseconds to a time with days, hours, minutes and seconds, but I'm not succeeding.

My original df looks like this:

```
ID         TIME_NANOSECONDS     
1          47905245000000000                       
2          45018244000000000                       
3          40182582000000000
```

The result should look like this:

```
ID         TIME_NANOSECONDS          TIME
1          47905245000000000         554 days 11:00:45.000000000               
2          45018244000000000         521 days 01:04:04.000000000 
3          40182582000000000         465 days 01:49:42.000000000
```

I've found some answers that advised to use timedelta, but following code, returns a date, which is not what I want.

```
temp_fc_col['TIME_TO_REPAIR_D'] = datetime.timedelta(temp_fc_col['TIME_TO_REPAIR'], unit='ns')
```

alternatively,

```
temp_fc_col['TIME_TO_REPAIR_D'] = (timedelta(microseconds=round(temp_fc_col['TIME_TO_REPAIR'], -3)
```

Returns an error: unsupported type for timedelta microseconds component: Series. Probably, because this staement can only process one value at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) working well with `Series`, also `unit='ns'` should be omit:

```
temp_fc_col['TIME_TO_REPAIR_D'] = pd.to_timedelta(temp_fc_col['TIME_NANOSECONDS'])
print (temp_fc_col)
   ID   TIME_NANOSECONDS  TIME_TO_REPAIR_D
0   1  47905245000000000 554 days 11:00:45
1   2  45018244000000000 521 days 01:04:04
2   3  40182582000000000 465 days 01:49:42
```